# How do I install Fortran compiler using cygwin on a Windows 7 32-bit machine?

Tags: fortran, cygwin

How do I install a Fortran compiler using cygwin on a Windows 7 32-bit machine?

Comment: This is a pretty bad question, and you're getting downvoted as a result. What have you tried so far, and what is going wrong? Why can't you just google fortran using cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cygwin packages gfortran, see the results here (for x86, that is 32-bit) https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=gfortran&arch=x86

I suggest that you pick that most recent, `gcc-fortran-6.3.0-1`. You can install it as any other cygwin package.

Comment: I installed the latest compiler as you suggested but I am not sure which FORTRAN version to use as the file extension. What extension should I save the file with and should I use `gfortran hello.f -o hello.exe` on the command line?

Comment: For "old-style" fortran 77 (meaning that the program file uses the first columns as reserved columns), it is `.f`. For so-called "free-form", that is `.f90`. This link http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Tutorials has introductory references that cover this difference.